# Improve ffmpeg scene detection in particular scenario

Tags: video, ffmpeg, detection, scene

I have 50 hours of video where a speaker is in the lower right corner of the video and the by far larger part of the video consists of slides in the center. The speaker moves a bit, the slides transition into the video. I need to detect the time codes of the slide transitions. +- 1 second precision is fine. I am playing around with select filters in ffmpeg such as `ffmpeg -i lecture.mp4  -filter:v "select='gt(scene,0.1)',showinfo"   -f null -`  but I have remaining problems where some help or hint would be highly appreciated.

**Problem 1:** Speaker movement occasionally triggers false positives. If there is some possibility to restrict frame comparison to a certain (spatial, cropped) area of the scene then I could focus on the slide area and this would greatly help.

**Problem 2:** Speed of slide transition is slow so I occasionally miss a transition since the change from frame(n) to frame(n+1) is too small. It would be great if I could compare, for example, frame(n) to frame(n+10) for threshold detection. [ffmpeg scene detection: check only every nth frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54980691/ffmpeg-scene-detection-check-only-every-nth-frame) does not help here, because it only checks every n-th frame but still compares a frame with its immediate neighbor.

Of course, both problems can be solved by producing a cropped version with reduced framerate. However, I am looking for a solution where I can do this in a single pass with some complex filter expression ... and this is exactly the place where my own experience with ffmpeg fails me and where I would appreciate some help.

**Problem 3:** Occasionally a single slide transition triggers several times in a row throughout the transition. I have no idea how to solve this in ffmpeg.

Comment: Do the slides have any animation or intra-slide 'activity'?

Comment: There is a very small amount of background animation which we can neglect. The slides themselves have no animation or intra-slide activity.

Comment: ad 2) you *can* do that in single pass provided you crop and detect at the same time, using -filter_complex would probably be sufficient, prepending "crop" filter to your chain.

Comment: ad initial problem: You can probably crop and detect at the same time (see previous comment) and insert the output into excel, then calculate diff between detections, filtering only detections happening >1s after another. This will filter out fast transitions, missing the possible slide changes with 1Hz or higher rate, however you will only have to look ahead for possible change manually.

Comment: May I ask what the original idea is? What is the end product?

Comment: The slides have no animation.

Comment: I need the time codes for providing pointers into the transitions and to enable me to do some editing when injecting / removing / rearranging.